# Tainting in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

So trying to figure how tainting in k8s will work , i have following setting at kubelet yaml spec, i am slightly confused what will be value at register-with-taints given that i want to only allow certain pod's to be placed on this node....rest all POD's should drop or or for any other pod then specific pod node should behave unschedulable.

```html
        --container-runtime=docker \
        --register-node=true \
        --allow-privileged=true \
        --register-schedulable=false \
        --register-with-taints=
        --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
```

Answer (score 7):

The `--register-with-taints` argument to `kubelet` is a node-level argument and registers the node with the given list of taints.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) is the documentation about `--register-with-taints`:

```
--register-with-taints []api.Taint
    Register the node with the given list of taints (comma separated "=:").
    No-op if register-node is false.
```

If `--register-with-taints` is set, it should be of the form `<key>=<value>:<effect>` (or comma separated like `<key1>=<value1>:<effect1>,<key2>=<value2>:<effect2>`).

> i want to only allow certain pods to be placed on this node

To do this:

1. Pass something like `--register-with-taints=key=value:NoSchedule` to `kubelet`. This means that no pod will be able to schedule onto this node unless it has a matching toleration.
2. Now, to allow a certain pod to be placed on this node, specify a toleration matching the above taint for the pod in the PodSpec yaml. Both of the following tolerations "match" the above taint, and thus a pod with either toleration below would be able to schedule onto the node:

   ```
   tolerations:
   - key: "key"
     operator: "Equal"
     value: "value"
     effect: "NoSchedule"

   ---- OR ----

   tolerations:
   - key: "key"
     operator: "Exists"
     effect: "NoSchedule"
   ```

More information about taints and tolerations in Kubernetes is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/).

Comment: thanks, but is taint right solution for saying schedule this pod only on this node and not on any other node, for example if i just want a pod to stick to etcd node can i do that using taint ? i do not want this pod to go to any other node per say other than etcd, how can i achieve this?

Comment: @Nik, yes, it is possible using `nodeSelector` or `Affinity/anti-affinity`. More info about assigning pods to specific nodes is in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/.